# jekyll serve ERROR `/sw.js' not found

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-theme

I get the following error after using jekyll serve

```
[2018-07-06 09:42:43] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=7146 port=4000
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
[2018-07-06 09:43:03] DEBUG accept: 127.0.0.1:45172
[2018-07-06 09:43:03] DEBUG Jekyll::Commands::Serve::Servlet is invoked.
[2018-07-06 09:43:03] DEBUG Jekyll::Commands::Serve::Servlet is invoked.
[2018-07-06 09:43:03] DEBUG Jekyll::Commands::Serve::Servlet is invoked.
[2018-07-06 09:43:04] DEBUG Jekyll::Commands::Serve::Servlet is invoked.
[2018-07-06 09:43:04] ERROR `/sw.js' not found.
[2018-07-06 09:43:04] DEBUG close: 127.0.0.1:45172
```

The error occurs every time I reload the page in the Firefox browser, not during build.

Where does that come from? I couldn't find any file in my project directory that contains sw.js

I use the minima theme

Answer (score 1):

The `sw.js` file can be anything :) but I've seen this file created automatically by the REACT framework. It includes some caching information and the name is short for `service worker`.

The easiest way to avoid this error os to check where this file should be found using your browser's console and then create it in that location.

However, I assume that your theme needs this file, generally through a node_modul and you should see how to avoid needing it and thus fix this issue permanently.

Comment: "where this file should" - should what?